# How do i launch a url in monodevelop c#?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am trying to find something in the gnome libs to do this:

```
Gnome.GnomeOpen(url_string);
```

and gnome will open the URL with the preferred gnome application

Does this exist?

Comment: i also just discovered
Gnome.Url.Show(link);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process.Start should handle all the messy work for you:

```
Process.Start ("http://www.mono-project.com");
```

Comment: What namespace is Process in? There's no `System.Process` as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents=false; 
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "xdg-open"; //best guess
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string_url;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I don't have linux here at work to test this, but you should be able to accomplish what you want by changing the command to what it needs to be, using the above as a template.

Comment: This will work on a recent Linux, but it's not portable. However, as jpobst said, Process.Start can open HTTP URLs (and most files) directly, using the appropriate handler on Mac/Windows/Linux - which in the case of Linux would indeed be xdg-open. You can disable this behaviour by setting proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false.

Comment: In 2020 this solution works very well even in Windows Linux Subsytem 2, where the accepted answer causes the app crash in the following conditions:
- WLS 2 in Windows 10 20H2
- Debian 10
- Latest Monodevelop
- VcxSrv installed to show GUI apps from WLS2